# thrust for_each example not running

Tags: cuda, thrust

I am trying to run the thrust for_each example described at http://docs.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/group__modifying.html, but am getting errors when I compile and run.

I use the following file: fe.cu:

```
#include <thrust/for_each.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct printf_functor{
    __host__ __device__
    void operator()(int x){
        printf("%d\n");
    }
};

int main(){
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_vec(3);
    d_vec[0] = 0; d_vec[1] = 1; d_vec[2] = 2;
    thrust::for_each(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end(), printf_functor());
}
```

and I compile with `nvcc -arch=sm_20 fe.cu`.

when I run using ./a.out, I get the following output:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'thrust::system::system_error'
  what():  unspecified launch failure
Aborted
```

Below is some information on the GPU used to run the code:

```
   --- General Information for device 0 ---
Name:  Tesla C2075
Compute capability:  2.0
Clock rate:  1147000
Device copy overlap:  Enabled
Kernel execution timeout :  Disabled
   --- Memory Information for device 0 ---
Total global mem:  5636554752
Total constant Mem:  65536
Max mem pitch:  2147483647
Texture Alignment:  512
   --- MP Information for device 0 ---
Multiprocessor count:  14
Shared mem per mp:  49152
Registers per mp:  32768
Threads in warp:  32
Max threads per block:  1024
Max thread dimensions:  (1024, 1024, 64)
Max grid dimensions:  (65535, 65535, 65535)
```

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that the thrust google code repo was deprecated and moved to github about two years ago. Those examples are effectively abandonware and there are definitely bug fixes in the github repo not reflected at google code.

Comment: There error appears to be in the [public github documentation](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__modifying.html#gacef91d7036641ffd9a9a483ff760de05) as well.  It's true that there could be a fix in the doxygen source in the github repo which is not represented publicly, yet.

Answer (score 6):

Probably you meant this in your code:

```
    printf("%d\n", x);
```

instead of this:

```
    printf("%d\n");
```

When I make that change to your code, it compiles and runs successfully for me.

I acknowledge the error in the documentation, and will report it on the [thrust googlegroup thrust-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/thrust-users).

Comment: As of today (April 5th, 2014), this misprint doesn't seem to be fixed, see [Group Modifying](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__modifying.html).